# Document Reference of Install SSL Certificate for Acumatica Website

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know where can I find document of step by step to install SSL Certificate and then change the http into https in acumatica website ?

I already search some of link reference regarding of this topic, but is there any other document/reference from acumatica related to this topic ?

Thanks

Comment: If you already have the SSL certificate look the second part of this link https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/iis-7.htm

Comment: I've tried based on your reference link, but our acumatica website still use port: 80 (http) and not use port: 443 (https). How to change mandatory port from 80 into 443 in IIS ?

Comment: So you have written the url with `https` and it is working with `http`?

Comment: yes, both of http and https is worked. But when I try launch the site from acumatica erp configuration > company maintenance, the site go to http protocols by default, and do not use https protocol.

Comment: From the Acumatica ERP Configuration exe seems like it is always setting url with `http` even in case of enabled only `https`.

Comment: so, how can I change the default protocol into https ? but I can still access the website using http protocol also

Answer (score 1):

By this [link](https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/iis-7.htm) you can find instructions on how to create and set SSL Certificate on the IIS Server.

One way to allow accessing the site only by `HTTPS` is to remove binding for `HTTP`, see below:
[image]

After that in the right panel in the IIS Server you will see only URL with `https`
[image]

And you will get a response like below if you try to access the site by `HTTP`
[image]